# Can't understand this part of the text

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The text is:

"The platonic ideal of Mac and Cheese Eric Kim’s new recipe, inspired by stouffer’s, delivers the same molten creaminess."

the part that puzzles me is:

"Mac and Cheese Eric Kim’s new recipe"

I know "Eric Kim’s new recipe" is a new recipe Eric Kim contived. But what would be:

"Mac and Cheese Eric Kim"???

Comment: You can improve this question by linking to the source .  Probabaly https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/04/dining/baked-macaroni-cheese-recipe-homemade.html  But you need to confirm that and not leave us to guess.#

Answer (score 2):

I am all but certain that this is not meant to be read as a single sentence, but rather as a title and then a sub-title:

> **The Platonic Ideal of Mac and Cheese**
> Eric Kim's new recipe, inspired by stouffer's [*sic*], delivers the same molten creaminess.

The first line is the headline or title of the review, and the next line is a *very* brief synopsis of the reviewer's opinion.

Comment: Given that "The Platonic Ideal of Macaroni and Cheese" turns up as news headlines, +1. Otherwise it *could* mean "A new recipe from Eric Kim, known for his Mac and Cheese ..."

Comment: I understand that 'mac and cheese' is a popular American meal, and that 'mac' is short for 'macaroni'.